# Helm chart - Set array to tls.hosts along static value

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

What I'm trying to achieve is to set an array of values into the hosts field in my ingress chart similar to:

```
spec:
  tls:
    hosts:
      - domain1
      - domain2
      - domain3
```

The problem I'm facing is that I have a default domain (domain1) and an array of extra domains (domain2, domain3) which is not of a fixed length.

What I tried was to iterate through the array along the default value

```
- hosts:
  - {{.Values.domain}}
  {{- range $key, $val := .Values.regionalDomain }}
    - {{ $val }}
  {{- end }}
```

But I get errors similar to: `spec.tls[0].hosts: Invalid value: "domain1 - domain2 - domain3": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')`

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier work with data in templates where possible, rather than trying to format yaml.

[`values`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#values) can pull information out of a dictionary into a list.
[`prepend`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#prepend-mustprepend) can add to the list.
[`toJson`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#tojson-musttojson) deals with the formatting.

```
hosts: {{ prepend (values .Values.regionalDomain) .Values.domain | toJson }}
```

Answer (score 1):

YAML is very whitespace-sensitive, and the interaction with the Helm/Go templating can be a little tricky.  It looks like there are two extra spaces on the items inside the `range` loop, so you should be able to change:

```yaml
- hosts:
  - {{.Values.domain}}
  {{- range $key, $val := .Values.regionalDomain }}
  {{/* The - lines up with the above -- two fewer indent spaces */}}
  - {{ $val }}
  {{- end }}
```

The templating isn't really aware of YAML syntax, and treats spaces very literally.  The `{{- ...` with a hyphen inside the braces will delete all whitespace, both newlines and spaces, on one side or the other of a template, and reasoning about this can involve consciously counting the newlines.  (There is not a newline immediately after the default domain, but there is a newline before every item inside the `range` loop and after its `end`, which is the correct number of newlines.)

If you're getting a YAML parse error, it can be useful to run `helm template` with your set of values, find the item in question, and make sure the generated YAML actually looks correct (there isn't a missing newline, the indentation lines up).